# Confusion about "No qualifying bean of type...RedisConnectionFactory"

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-redis

Since the different configs, I have written two LettuceConnectionFactory:

1. ItemFactoryConfig
2. ActivityFactoryConfig

the code as follows:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:config/redis.properties", encoding = "UTF-8")
public class ItemFactoryConfig {
    @Value("${item.host}")
    private String host;
    @Value("${item.port}")
    private int port;

    @Bean
    public LettuceConnectionFactory itemFactory(){
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();
        redisConfiguration.setHostName(host);
        redisConfiguration.setPort(port);
        return new LettuceConnectionFactory(redisConfiguration);
    }
}



@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:config/redis.properties", encoding = "UTF-8")
public class ActivityFactoryConfig {

    @Value("${activity.host}")
    private String host;
    @Value("${activity.port}")
    private int port;

    @Bean
    public LettuceConnectionFactory activityFactory(){
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();
        redisConfiguration.setHostName(host);
        redisConfiguration.setPort(port);
        return new LettuceConnectionFactory(redisConfiguration);
    }
}
```

And I added @Qualifier when these LettuceConnectionFactories were autowired.

```
@Configuration
public class ItemTemplateConfig {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("itemFactory")
    private LettuceConnectionFactory itemFactory;

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, String> itemTemplate(){...}
}



@Configuration
public class ActivityTemplateConfig {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("activityFactory")
    private LettuceConnectionFactory activityFactory;

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, String> activityTemplate(){...}
}
```

However, spring boot still report the NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: activityFactory,itemFactory
```

Spring boot Description:

Parameter 0 of method redisTemplate in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisAutoConfiguration required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - activityFactory: defined by method 'activityFactory' in class path resource [com/lyf/redisdemo/config/Activity/ActivityFactoryConfig.class]
    - itemFactory: defined by method 'itemFactory' in class path resource [com/lyf/redisdemo/config/Item/ItemFactoryConfig.class]

Action:

Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed

spring boot: 2.1.0.RELEASE

Comment: You have to set one of the `LettuceConnectionFactory` as `@Primary`, and continue using your custom `RedisTemplate`'s, why did you create another question? :)

Comment: emm..I think the question may be not a same type..haha.. I have already tried to set @Primary on "itemFactory". Although the exception disappears, another template(ActivityTemplate)  has read the itemFactory's configuration..this result is not such as I expect..

Comment: Can you put them all in the same config class? & call factory build methods directly within template bean methods? Check my answer on the other question. That would resolve your issue hopefully.

Comment: This problem has been bothering me for two days. I have reconstructed my code according to your method, but the problem is still the same. I sent the code to your Hotmail. Please check it. Sorry about my presumptuous. Thank you.

Comment: any solution for that?

Comment: One solution is provide @Primary to one connection factory